# In stress testing ,while executing script on Jmeter tool getting token session expired

Tags: jmeter

while executing script on jmeter getting token session expired error showing in below image, searched on google and tried to solve,it is not solved

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you recorded the test using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) and the token which is used for authentication purposes has limited time to live so once it has expired it cannot be used anymore.

As your application suggests you need to perform the login process once again, then extract the token using a suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), save it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and replace recorded value with the variable from the previous step.

The whole process of handling dynamic parameters is known as [**correlation**](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter) and there is a lot of information on the topic in the Internet with examples.